# Test integral for convergence

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I have to test for which values of $y$ the following integral converges:

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan\left(x^{3}\right)\ln\left(1 + x^{2}\right)}{x^{y}}
\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

I have tried some different ways, but I failed. Any hints ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand is a continuous function over $(0,\infty)$, potential issues are as $x \to 0^+$ and as $x \to \infty$.

- As $x \to 0^+$, on gets $$ \frac{\arctan\left(x^{3}\right)\ln\left(1
   - x^{2}\right)}{x^{y}} \sim -x^{5-y} $$ giving a convergent integral iff $y-5<1$.
- As $x \to \infty$, on gets $$
     \frac{\arctan\left(x^{3}\right)\ln\left(1 + x^{2}\right)}{x^{y}} \sim
     \pi \,\frac{\ln x}{x^y} $$ giving a convergent integral iff $y>1$.

Then you can conclude.

Comment: Near $\infty $, it is equivalent to Bertrand integral.

Answer (score 1):

**hint near 0 **

The integrand is equivalent to

$$\frac {x^3.x^2}{x^y}\sim \frac{1}{x^{y-5}} $$

so, near 0, it converges if $$y-5<1\iff <6.$$

Comment: You mean y-5<1 ?

Comment: I think in your first step you mean $y<6$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Yes of course, Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is $y - 5 < 1$, but he fixed it.